# What's the best way to write `indexBy` in Scala?

Tags: algorithm, scala

Underscore.js has a function [indexBy](http://underscorejs.org/#indexBy) which does the following:

> Given a list, and an iteratee function that returns a key for each
>   element in the list (or a property name), returns an object with an
>   index of each item. Just like groupBy, but for when you know your keys
>   are unique.
>
> ```
> var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
> _.indexBy(stooges, 'age');
> => {
>   "40": {name: 'moe', age: 40},
>   "50": {name: 'larry', age: 50},
>   "60": {name: 'curly', age: 60}
> }
> ```

What's the best way to write this in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final case class Stooge(name: String, age: Int)

val stooges = Seq(Stooge("moe", 40), Stooge("larry", 50))

val result = stooges.map(s => s.age -> s).toMap

println(result)
// Map(40 -> Stooge(moe,40), 50 -> Stooge(larry,50))
```